# Sonata Admin Bundle 2 admin page for 1 entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to create 2 admin page for 1 entity, but patterns are the same:

php app/console route:debug

```
dis_codes_companies_list              ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/list
dis_codes_companies_create            ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/create
dis_codes_companies_batch             ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/batch
dis_codes_companies_edit              ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/{id}/edit
dis_codes_companies_delete            ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/{id}/delete
dis_codes_companies_show              ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/{id}/show
dis_codes_companies_export            ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/export
dis_codes_companies_set_premium       ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/{id}/setpremium
dis_codes_personal_list               ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/list
dis_codes_personal_create             ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/create
dis_codes_personal_batch              ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/batch
dis_codes_personal_edit               ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/{id}/edit
dis_codes_personal_delete             ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/{id}/delete
dis_codes_personal_show               ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/{id}/show
dis_codes_personal_export             ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/export
dis_codes_personal_set_premium        ANY      /admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/{id}/setpremium
```

Where I can change route pattern? If I do that in RouteCollection class, I have an error:

```
No route found for "GET /admin/mobispot/discodes/personal/list"
```

Comment: You probably have a conflict in routes, this helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828072/sonataadminbundle-multiple-admin-section-for-same-entity

Comment: yep - its a dupe. See the linked question for the fix

Answer (score 0):

You can change routes in AdminClass in configureRoutes method

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $router) {
    $router->add('copy', $this->getRouterIdParameter() . '/copy');
    $router->add('getSubProjects', $this->getRouterIdParameter() . '/getSubProjects');
}
```